# Silhouette score behaving counter intuitively

Tags: clustering, k-means

My Silhouette score decreases as number of clusters increase. I'm using scikit's kmeans algorithm on the modified white wine dataset from UCI. Here's the final dataset I'm using - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1goh97QZB3V0rJSn4amLC-jBb3upsaIlH

Code

```
df = pd.read_csv('whiteWineTwoClasses.csv', header=0)
numberOfColumns = len(df.columns)
numberOfAttributes = numberOfColumns - 1
X = df.iloc[:,0:numberOfColumns-1]
Y = df.iloc[:, numberOfColumns-1]
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
xtrans = scaler.transform(X)

def getNumbersForKmeans(X, numberOfClusters):
  kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=numberOfClusters, random_state=0)
  kmeans.fit(X)
  labels = kmeans.labels_
  inertiaScore = kmeans.inertia_
  silScore = metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels, metric='euclidean')
  return inertiaScore, silScore


print(getNumbersForKmeans(xtrans, 3))
print(getNumbersForKmeans(xtrans, 10))
print(getNumbersForKmeans(xtrans, 20))
print(getNumbersForKmeans(xtrans, 50))
print(getNumbersForKmeans(xtrans, df.shape[0]-1))
```

Output is (Look at second column)

```
(43830.24610203885, 0.13157830778113577)
(31412.978722003416, 0.11319449812661529)
(26173.031185455613, 0.10728651926177515)
(19896.193919556117, 0.10876065019480499)
(2.5006777281554326e-07, 0.00010210332874983413)
```

I was of the understanding that when the number of clusters are ~ number of data points, silhouette score should be ~1

I've looked at other answers but none of them seemed to actually help here.

Comment: Please post not the code (or not only it) but also results: cluster membership variable for each k, silhouette value for each k. You should also tell whether you standardized your variables in clustering or not.

Comment: 1. Hey, I've posted silhoutte scores (Second column) I cannot paste cluster membership because it's 4800 row data. 
2. By standardizing, do you mean this - xtrans = scaler.transform(X)? I've done this in the code.

Comment: I have similar issue. In my case as the number of clusters increases samples having positive silhouette score decreases and negative increases. Where you able to find what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption on Silhouette is wrong:

The silhouette of a one elemental cluster leads to a division by zero (there is no average distance to *other* members of the same cluster).
The authors defined the value of one-elemental clusters to be 0.

So when k -> N then Silhouette tends to 0 *by definition*.